# Split a large dataframe into multiple dataframes by row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, subset

I have a large dataframe with over 1m records by over 40 variables that I want to run through a loop for values update to prevent glitch, and the size of the file varies each time. I would like split the over 1m rows into n smaller sets, each with a new dataframe name such as ending with 1,2,...,n, newdf1, newdf2, newdf3,... . The split function in R only split the vector but it is still in that dataframe, not creating multiple subset of the dataframe which I would need to retain the data type in the 40 variables. I don't have any values to split by column, I just want to split by the row number in order.

Comment: You can use `split`..  If you show the example, it is easier to know what exactly is the issue in `split`

Comment: I tried but it didn't create new multiple data frames. I want to index to the values in the column.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: If you want the data frame in groups of `n` rows each try `split(df, seq(nrow(df)) %/% n)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example where we generate a data frame with 1 million rows, split it into 20 groups, name the data frames in the resulting list, and run `summary()` on the first data frame in the list by extracting it with the `$` operator by name.

```
set.seed(90125)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(40000000,mean = 25,sd=5),ncol=40))
# make group number start with 1, as remainders
# vary from 0 - 19
df$group <- 1:1000000 %% 20 + 1
dfList <- split(df,df$group)
```

At this point there are two copies of the data in memory: the original data frame, `df`, and a second copy that is split into 20 different data frames within the list `dfList`.

We can demonstrate this with the `length()` function:

```
> length(dfList)
[1] 20
```

Each data frame has 50,000 observations, which we can demonstrate with the `nrow()` function:

```
> nrow(dfList[[1]])
[1] 50000
```

We can assign names to the data frames with a combination of `names()` and `paste0()`.

```
# add names to the list and print the names
names(dfList) <- paste0("data",1:20)
names(dfList)
> names(dfList)
 [1] "data1"  "data2"  "data3"  "data4"  "data5"  "data6"  "data7"  "data8" 
 [9] "data9"  "data10" "data11" "data12" "data13" "data14" "data15" "data16"
[17] "data17" "data18" "data19" "data20"
```

Once the data frames have been named, they can be accessed from the list via the `$` form of the extract operator. We'll generate a summary of the first data frame, accessing it by name.

```
summary(dfList$data1[1:5])
```

...and the output:

```
> summary(dfList$data1[1:5])
       V1                V2               V3              V4        
 Min.   :-0.7251   Min.   : 2.481   Min.   : 3.02   Min.   : 3.173  
 1st Qu.:21.5919   1st Qu.:21.603   1st Qu.:21.57   1st Qu.:21.526  
 Median :24.9990   Median :24.982   Median :24.97   Median :24.914  
 Mean   :24.9968   Mean   :24.978   Mean   :24.97   Mean   :24.931  
 3rd Qu.:28.3971   3rd Qu.:28.330   3rd Qu.:28.32   3rd Qu.:28.357  
 Max.   :45.7101   Max.   :44.730   Max.   :48.03   Max.   :45.506  
       V5        
 Min.   : 2.427  
 1st Qu.:21.595  
 Median :25.010  
 Mean   :24.997  
 3rd Qu.:28.406  
 Max.   :44.199  
>
```

**NOTE:** the original data frame consumes about 312.8Mb, so after execution of the `split()` function, the two copies of data will consume about 625.6Mb of RAM. One can use the `rm()` function to remove the original data frame from RAM if necessary.

Comment: Hi, if I want to do the same thing but with columns. For example, I have a `df` with 105 columns. I want to create 10 small `df` with 15 columns in each but first 5 columns will be present in all small `dfs`. What would I need to do?

Comment: @zillurrahman -- you can use the extract operator to select the columns to be included in the output data frames, such as `df[,1:5]`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a minimally reproducible example with some sample data, I think that I have an idea of what you're trying to accomplish. Lets say that you have a data set of 10000 rows, and want to split your data into separate data frames of 100 rows each. You could subset the larger data frame into a list of smaller data frames based on the length that you want those smaller data frames to be.

```r
####  Some dummy data here ####
colA <- rep(c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), 2000)
colB <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 3, sd = 0.25)
colC <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 1, sd = 1)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(colA, colB, colC), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#### Create an empty list to be filled with your subset data frames ####
dataList <- list()

#### Since it's 10000 rows total, and you want 100 smaller data frames, ####
#### create an iterator variable that you can reference for subsetting. ####
listIterator <- seq(0,99,1)

for(i in listIterator){
  dataList[[i+1]] <- df[c((1+(100*i)):(100+(100*i))),]  
}

dataList[1]
dataList[2]
```

You could then subset the list of data frames into whichever data frame you're going to work with at a particular time . . .

```r
df1 <- dataList[1]
```

Or reference particular columns within each

```r
dataList[[1]]$colA
```

Comment: Worth it to say to use purrr::map() command to work with that kind of list